# Dynamic HtmlSelect options not posting back

Tags: asp.net

I have cascading dropdowns (country/province/city).  when the page posts back I lose the selected option for province and city.  The options for country are loaded through .net code but the province and city options are populated through javascript.

I think this has something to do with viewstate but can't quite wrap my head around why the selected values aren't posting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options added to a dropdown (html select) list using JavaScript won't work.
This is modifying values in the DOM client side and not the ViewState from the server.

This post should answer it all with a detailed explanation.
[Options added to <select> by javascript lost in postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271172/options-added-to-select-by-javascript-lost-in-postback)

You could attempt to add and remove selected options dynamically in Javascript using a mix of Javascript and JQuery but it could get messy and slow fast.

```
    function setSelectedValue(value) {
        var x = document.getElementById("yourDivId").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("yourDivId").options;

        $('#yourDivId option').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('selected')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            }
        });

        y[x].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
```