# DropDownList selection is not reflected in server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in my asp.net web page. Its a server side control. I am doing a ajax call and inside the ajax call I am adding a new item to the ddl and setting it as selected. It is showing nicely on page. But when I do a post back the selected item gives me the old selected item in the dropdownlist.

```
// ddlCaseNumber is the id of the dropdownlist and its clientid property is set
// to static.
// Removes the selected attribute of selected selected item .
$('#ddlCaseNumber option:selected').removeAttr("selected");

// Add the new item to dropdownlist.
$('#ddlCaseNumber').append('<option selected="selected" value=' + crmid + '>' 
                           + crmid + '</option>');

// Code behind code to get the new value.
// This line is giving the old value instead of giving new value.
string strNewValue = ddlCaseNumber.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the new item added in code behind?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271172/options-added-to-select-by-javascript-lost-in-postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items added dynamically on the client will **NOT** be automatically replicated on the server on a post-back.

One option is to somehow store that the new items has been added (in something like a `<input type="hidden">` or `<asp:HiddenField>`) and then manually add the item as part of your page `Init` on the post-back.

Another option would be to call AJAX to store the information on the server in something like a `Session` variable, and then again add it manually on the post-back.