# Fill server DropDown with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to add drop down items throught javascript, and then get it on server side?

I have

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="testDropDown" CssClass="listClass" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Добавить" OnClick="saveButtonClick" />
```

After page load javascript add items to drop down

```
$('.listClass').append("<option value='value1'>Text1</option>");
```

But after saveButton click i have empty drop down on server

Comment: Thanks evrybody for help. I'll use hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any dynamic changes that happen on the client-side will not be automatically replicated on the server side.

You need to record the fact the action took place somehow (using, for instance an `<asp:HiddenField>` control)... then on the post-back, check for whether the action happened and replicate the value that took place on the client.

Also, be careful, as ASP.NET will probably throw an exception due to the fact that control is returning a value that ASP.NET did not populate the control with in the first place.  To counteract this, either set the `EnableEventValidation="false"` in your `<@Page>` declaration, or add all possible values using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in ASP.NET because the values are contructed using the ViewState on the server side.

Check this. It may be helpful for you: [Options added to <select> by javascript lost in postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271172/options-added-to-select-by-javascript-lost-in-postback)