# Getting selected value as null of city dropdown on inserting record in table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have 2 dropdown controls State and City in which i am filling city dropdown with ajax jquery
by calling Web method from server side but on submit event i am not getting selected value.

This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" onchange=" LoadCity();"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>



function LoadCity() {
    var select = document.getElementById("<%= ddlState.ClientID %>");
       var id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
       $.ajax({
           url: "/Abc.aspx/LoadCity",
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: '{stateId: "' + id + '"}',
           contentType: "application/json",
           success: function (responce) {
               var html = '<option value="0">Select City</option>';
               $(responce.d).each(function () {
                   html += '<option value="' + this.Value + '">' + this.Text + '</option>'
               });
               $(document.getElementById("<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>")).html(html);
            }
    });



[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> LoadCity(int stateId)
{
    var data = this.ReturnCity(stateId);
    return data;
}

 public List<ListItem> ReturnCity(int stateId)
 {
     var data = context.CityMasters.Where(t => t.StateId == stateId).ToList()
                          .select(t=> new ListItem {Text=t.Name,Value=t.Id.ToString()}).ToList();
     return data;
 }
```

But now when i am getting selected value of City dropdown then i am getting empty value:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cityId=ddlCity.SelectedValue;//Getting null here;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how to get selected value of city on save event???

Comment: See the answer why it doesnt work and a workaround here - [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1271204/2401021)

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery ..

```
var selectedcity = $(select).val();
```

NOTE:

You haven't told us anything about a save event or shown us the code for that, the above line of code simply gets the currently selected value from your city drop down.

Comment: I want to get selected value of city on save event